# awk print does not work in bash -c

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I noticed that this works fine (will print only the PID of `unattended-upgrades` process):

```bash
lslocks | awk '/unattended-upgrades/ { print $2 }'
```

But this effectively ignores the `print` part (will print the entire line):

```bash
bash -c "lslocks | awk '/unattended-upgrades/ { print $2 }'"
```

This is an Ubuntu 18.04 and Bash version 4.4.20.

What is spacial about `bash -c` that causes this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing special about `bash -c` here - it's the fact that the outer double quotes permit expansion of `$2` by the interactive shell:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "echo foo bar | awk '{ print $2 }'"
+ bash -c 'echo foo bar | awk '\''{ print  }'\'''
foo bar
```

(The "gotcha" here is that single quotes are not special inside double quotes; the outer double quotes "preserve their literal value". See [Bash Reference Manual 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes).)

Compare:

```
$ bash -c "echo foo bar | awk '{ print \$2 }'"
+ bash -c 'echo foo bar | awk '\''{ print $2 }'\'''
bar
```

Comment: Ouch. That hurts.

Comment: @foki quoting and escaping in shell are always a pain.  It's something you just have to get used to and learn how to deal with...and it gets worse if you need multiple nested levels of quoting (e.g. with `bash -c`, `ssh`, and many others) as in your Q.  See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and be sure to follow the link to the [quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting) tag.

Comment: @cas Thank you for the references, they are very useful.